# SWIFT - XIB File call action from UITableviewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

I have a `UITableviewController` and I try to put in overlay a menu.

To do that I proceed as follow:

Into main controller I create a `UIview`, subclass of CustomView:

```
    class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    ..........
    // Placeholder view for custom view
    var overlayView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 12, y: 100, width: 300, height: 100))

    .........

// function that must be call from CustomView

    func testPrint(){

       println("testPrint")

    }

      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

    // add view on overlay to the UITableviwController
      self.view.addSubview(overlayView)

    ......... }

    ..... }
```

I add a `CustomView.xib` file

I add a `CustomView.swift` file

```
 import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    var view: UIView!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("test")

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        xibSetup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        view.frame = bounds

        view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight

        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)

        // Assumes UIView is top level and only object in CustomView.xib file
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }

}
```

wich way I must proceed?

I must call the testPrint() function stated in the main controller "MyTableViewController" from the `XIB` File and assign to it `CustomView.swift` as file owner

or

I must assign `MyTableViewController` as file owner of `XIB` and connect the button from `XIB` file directly to `MyTableViewController`

in this way I receive error:

2015-05-16 21:15:02.243 ETA[15578:2618934] Unknown class _TtC3ETA4menu in Interface Builder file. 2015-05-16 21:15:06.935 ETA[15578:2618934]
+[ETA. MyTableViewController pppp:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b40f8 2015-05-16 21:15:06.937 ETA[15578:2618934] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ETA. MyTableViewController myButtonMainController:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b40f8'

Thanks Alberto

Comment: Do the second option.Connect the button to CustomView.xib file and link it to buttonPressed method.

Comment: thanks, but how I can call a function that is stated into MyTableViewController?